# Construction of comparative sentences

Tags: comparative-constructions

Which of the following is correct/preferred?

1- Some have better chances of joining the final group than **do** others.

2- Some have better chances of joining the final group than others.

Does the response vary in spoken vs written English?

Comment: In written English, Google's Ngram shows the construction without "do" to be more common, but to my ear, both are correct. That said, your heading, concerning "superlatives," is not the *best* choice. "Comparative" would be *better*. See https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives

Comment: Both sound correct to _my_ ear too. By the way, "Some have _a better chance_ of joining..." might be more natural; unless the chances really are plural.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you for your help! Following your suggestion, I changed "superlative" to "comparative" in the question's title.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you for the helpful tips! I found both helpful!